# Unable to bind jquery dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have function and i'm trying to append return values to dropdown but its not helping at all.

here is my function

```
function GetNames(FROM,TO) {
 var inputObject = {};   
 inputObject.FROM = FROM;   
  inputObject.TO = TO;    
 $.ajax({   
     type: "POST",  
      url: "../WebService.asmx/getName",   
      data: {from : inputObject.FROM ,to : inputObject.TO},   
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
      dataType: "json",   
      async: true,   
      success: function (msg) {   
        $.each(msg.d, function (k, value) {   
            $('#ddlName').append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "   </option>");   
        });   
     },   
         error: function (errMsg) {   
         alert(errMsg);   
     }   
  });   
}
```

I have change the data parameters to this values as well but they are not helping

```
1) data: JSON.stringify(inputObject),
2) data: {'from=' : inputObject.FROM, 'to=' : inputObject.TO},
3) data: {'from' : inputObject.FROM, 'to' : inputObject.TO},
```

none of these changes helping.

FROM and TO is dates I have test the webservice getName method and its working fine.
But this javascript method is keep going into error: function(errMsg) and the message coming up "Object : Object"

Web service method :

```
  [WebMethod]
    public List<string> getName(string from,string to)
    {
        List<string> bdnames= new List<string>();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            SqlParameter[] sqlparams = new SqlParameter[2];


            sqlparams[0] = new SqlParameter("@FROM", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlparams[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlparams[0].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(from);

            sqlparams[1] = new SqlParameter("@TO", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlparams[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlparams[1].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(to);

            ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(usmHelper.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "rep_getBDMs", sqlparams);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                bdnames.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UUMM"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return bdnames;
    }
```

Web service return values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>Samuel</string> 
  <string>Chetna</string> 
  <string>Chris</string> 
  <string>Mily</string> 
  <string>tuff</string> 
  <string>Prasad</string> 
  <string>Ram</string> 
  <string>Gary</string> 
  <string>MarkTaylor</string> 
  <string>Kenn</string> 
  </ArrayOfString>
```

Comment: its a value return by the webservice

Comment: paste the web service method code please

Comment: check browser console if you are seeing some error while executing the service call. Most likely you should be seeing something access origin errors.

Comment: Are you sure, you are using response msg correctly? try- `$.each(msg` instead of `$.each(msg.d`

Comment: @Watt Yes I have check that no error showing up just these two msgs and my page name. 
Refresh the page to see messages that may have occurred before the F12 tools were opened. 
HTML1201: localhost is a website you've added to Compatibility View.

Comment: hi @MohammadAdil $.each(msg its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very verbose version, but you might find some value:

```
function GetNames(FROM, TO) {
    // just use the object you created for data
    var inputObject = {
        from: FROM,
        to: TO
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebService.asmx/getName",
        data: inputObject,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        // figure out if it has .d or not and filter for that
        dataFilter: function (data) {
            var msg;
            if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function') msg = JSON.parse(data);
            else msg = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d')) return msg.d;
            else return msg;
        },
        // pass the filtered message (data returned) to a function
        success: function (msg) {
            loadOptions(msg);
        },
        // verbose error handler
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.status;
            alert(errorMessage);
            if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        }

    });
}
/* build the option list 
   This only hits the DOM once instead of your .each or  a .map etc.
*/
function loadOptions(jdata) {
    var bdnames = jdata.bdnames;
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < bdnames.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + bdnames[i].string + '">' + bdnames[i].string + '</option>';
    }
    $("select#ddlName").html(options);
}
```

Comment: Note I do not know for sure if you need  `var bdnames = jdata.bdnames;` or  `var bdnames = jdata;` right off as my brain is foggy at the moment :)

Comment: Hi, I have change LoadProcedure(msg); to loadOptions(msg); and I tried in both manner bdnames = jdata or bdnames = jdata.bdnames; its keep giving me this error : 
Ajax error:../WebService.asmx/getName : error : Internal Server Error : Internal Server Error : 500

Comment: I got another similar function where i'm not supplying any parameters and its working perfectly fine
`function GetH1Years() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebService.asmx/getYears",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
          $.each(msg.d, function (k, value) {
                $('#ddlyears').append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        });
        },
        error: function (jqXhr) {
        errorCaller(jqXhr);
    }
});}`

Comment: try this for data - `data: JSON.stringify(inputObject),` - google for the the JSON.stringify or search SO.

Comment: NOTE: the 500 error indicates the call to the server is incorrect, thus that last comment.  Adding this to the error: might help:  `alert(xhr.responseText);`